# I cannot select Java as an option when creating a new project in Android Studio 2021

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

I just updated to 2021.2.1 Patch 1. When I create a new project and select a material3 type, only kotlin is avalaible:

[image]

I'm not sure if it is because of the update because it has been long time since I did something for Android. However, if I don't select the material3 option Java is available. Can we use material3 with java? Really Google?

Comment: The "Language" drop-down controls the code that is generated for you by the new-project wizard. Apparently, they only have a Kotlin template for Material3. This does not prevent you from writing your own Java code. Jetpack Compose, on the other hand, does require Kotlin for its UI bits, though you can use Java for other aspects of the project if you so choose.