# How to create a new Basic Activity (Material 3) Java Project?

Tags: android-studio

After many years I want to develop a hobby Android Project again. Many things changed, Im a Java developer and want to create a Java Android Project.

In Android Studio I choose new "Basic Activity (Material 3) Project. The "language" section is greyed out, and I cant switch from kotlin to java. Is this new staff for kotlin only or its possbile to change the language to java?

Comment: I also stumble upon the same hurdle. I can't find much about it. Have you found any solution?

Comment: There is another thread for the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72862314/i-cannot-select-java-as-an-option-when-creating-a-new-project-in-android-studio

Comment: My solution was, to switch to Ionic v6 and build  a Hybrid App.